# How can I change the default save location of Office for Mac?

Tags: mac, ms-office, file

I have Office for Mac 2011 and unlike Office PC, I can't find how to change the location where my files are to be saved.

The default position doesn't suit my needs and I spend a lot of time "navigating" to the folder where I store all my projects.

I would like to open a file, edit it's contents, and "save as" a different file name, but to the same file folder from which the document was originally opened... just like you can on a PC.

Answer (score 8):

The File Locations preference pane allows to to specify the location for all documents to be saved.

In Word Preferences... select File Locations:

[image: screencap of Word prefs]

When in File Locations, set the path you want Word to use by clicking in the Location field. The default setting, which appears blank in the screencap below, is to ~/Documents.

[image]

Comment: When I change that setting, it seems to have no effect when I restart, create a new document, and then click save.  It defaults back to ~/Documents when I changed it and verified the modified setting.  I have Word version 14.4.4 (140807).

Comment: I think you need to make the location as blank. I made it to be in ~/Document and now it always tries to save in my ~/Document folder, which is not what we want!

Answer (score -1):

It's not in Apple preferences but in Word's own `Preferences`. See the drop down menu of `Word` in top left corner while the program is running, not the Apple symbol.

Comment: How does this differ from @IconDaemon ' s more complete answer?