# How to set the default folder for saving a Word document when the option is missing in File Locations?

Tags: ms-office

I want to set the default path or folder for saving Word documents, which should be possible according to an answer to [How can I change the default save location of Office for Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92234/how-can-i-change-the-default-save-location-of-office-for-mac/92238#92238). However when opening Settings and clicking on File Locations there is no option to set a folder for Documents. It is missing and I cannot add it. Logging in as an admin doesn't change it.

[image: missing Documents option in File Location settings]

Comment: Looks the same for me. Not sure you even can set a default location for documents.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92238

Comment: Looking at this answer it should be possible

Comment: That relates to an older version of Word, maybe it got removed in recent version

Comment: (there are some deleted "answers" below the original question which raise the same questions as you do here)